# Spark 1.6 drop columns based on value

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe

```
val max_col = df.select(df.columns.map(c => max(c)): _*)
```

gives me a 1 row dataframe with multiple columns. Many of these columns have value 0, i.e. there are no other values than 0 in these columns (all are positive numbers).

How do I select only the columns with max value > 0? I.e. how do I drop all columns (not rows, there are plenty of details on how to drop rows) where max greater than 0?

```
a b c d

1 7 0 1
```

Would like to have

```
a b d

1 7 1
```

With

```
val exprs = max_col.columns.map(c => when(col(c) !== 0, col(c)).otherwise("null").as(c))
val df_new = max_col.select(exprs:_*)
```

I can turn above to

```
a b c d

1 7 null 1
```

but no success in finding na.drop for columns.

Seems like a 'newbie' question, but didn't find a nice way, yet (I surfed the web for hours, realising (again) that Google certainly have problems with their service).

Any help would be much appreciated. Very.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
val df = Seq((1,7,0,1)).toDF("a", "b", "c", "d")

df.selectExpr(df.first().getValuesMap[Int](df.columns).filter(_._2 > 0).keys.toSeq: _*).show
+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  d|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  7|  1|
+---+---+---+
```

1. get the row object with `first()` function;
2. use `getValuesMap` to convert the row to a Map;
3. filter the Map based on values;
4. get the keys that satisfy the filter condition;
5. select the columns;